# Ajax Call Breaks When executed inside a function and throws a warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to DRY a JavaScript file that makes several ajax calls. I have a function that makes a ajax call, returns an object containing details needed for other ajax calls.

```js
const makeCall = (url, type, data, done) => {
    $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
        })
        .done(done)
        .fail(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
};

const country = await $.ajax({
        url: "libs/php/opencage.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",

        data: {
            LAT: x.coords.latitude,
            LNG: x.coords.longitude,
        },
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        if (result.status.name == "ok") {
            //populate the detail object with responses from opencage needed to communicate with other apis
            detail.lat = x.coords.latitude;
            detail.long = x.coords.longitude;
            detail.continent = result.data.results[0].components.continent;
            detail.countryName = result.data.results[0].components.country;
            detail.countryCode = result.data.results[0].components.country_code;

            let code = result.data.results[0].components.country_code;
            //set the select to user country
            console.log(code);
            $("#countrySelect").val(code.toUpperCase());
        }
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        // your error code

        console.log(error);
    });

//save needed part of detail object for easy access
let latitude = detail.lat;
let longitude = detail.long;
let countryName = noSpace(detail.countryName);
let countryCode = detail.countryCode;
let continent = detail.continent;

//makecall to retrieve geojson feature details for selected country.
makeCall(
    "libs/php/retrieveCountry.php",
    "GET", {
        code: countryCode.toUpperCase()
    },
    function(r) {
        //add the geojson object to the map
        L.geoJSON(r).addTo(map);
    }
);
```

This works well. To DRY the code, I made the awaited ajax call with the makeCall function. what happens is that the second makeCall to retrieveCountry.php doesnt execute as the gejson feature is never added to the map. I also get a warning: 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.ts(80007)

```js
const country = await makeCall(
    "libs/php/opencage.php",
    "GET", {
        LAT: x.coords.latitude,
        LNG: x.coords.longitude,
    },
    function(result) {
        if (result.status.name == "ok") {
            //populate the detail object with responses from opencage needed to communicate with other apis
            detail.lat = x.coords.latitude;
            detail.long = x.coords.longitude;
            detail.continent = result.data.results[0].components.continent;
            detail.countryName = result.data.results[0].components.country;
            detail.countryCode = result.data.results[0].components.country_code;

            let code = result.data.results[0].components.country_code;
            //set the select to user country
            console.log(code);
            $("#countrySelect").val(code.toUpperCase());
            return detail;
        }
    }
);

//save needed part of detail object for easy access
let latitude = detail.lat;
let longitude = detail.long;
let countryName = noSpace(detail.countryName);
let countryCode = detail.countryCode;
let continent = detail.continent;

//makecall to retrieve geojson feature details for selected country. This part is never implemented as this feature is not added to the map.
makeCall(
    "libs/php/retrieveCountry.php",
    "GET", {
        code: countryCode.toUpperCase()
    },
    function(r) {
        //add the geojson object to the map
        L.geoJSON(r).addTo(map);
    }
);
```

Please what could be wrong? Also worth adding is that the entire code is inside an async function and the detail object is locally scoped to this async function

Comment: Did you mean to `return` from `makeCall`?  For example: `return $.ajax(...)` ?

Comment: `$.ajax()` doesn't return a Promise, there's no use in awaiting it.

Comment: @DallogFheir — `$.ajax()` returns a thenable which is compatible with a promise. It can be `await`ed just fine.

Comment: I want the first Ajax request to be made first, before the second, as the data for the second is provided by the first Ajax call. And I want to make the Ajax calls with the makeCall function

Comment: So get with modern times and drop jquery's ajax and use fetch.

Comment: or at least axios!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is awaiting the AJAX operation, and the warning is the clue as to why.  Specifically it's telling you that `await` does nothing here:

```
await makeCall(...)
```

This is because `makeCall` is not awaitable.  It's not `async` and it doesn't return anything:

```
const makeCall = (url, type, data, done) => {
  $.ajax(...);
};
```

Since the `$.ajax()` operation *is* awaitable, it appears that your intent was to return that:

```
const makeCall = (url, type, data, done) => {
  return $.ajax(...);
};
```

This will return the awaitable ("then-able") result from `$.ajax()` itself, which consuming code could then `await` (or follow with `.then()`).